# if else condition not working fine always runs else

Tags: iphone, ios, if-statement

I am using if else condition to check variable but it always runs else also when value is true then it also show else

```
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",data);

if ([data isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) {

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:@"Successful Login" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}  
else {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Incorrect user name or password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
```

Comment: check there data string may be issue YES or yes or Yes some capitalize issue

Comment: if( [@"Some String" caseInsensitiveCompare:@"some string"] == NSOrderedSame ) {   } check with case senstive ?

Comment: The output from your NSLog call would be really nice in helping the debug along.

Comment: can we see the ouput of NSLog(@"%@",data); ?

Comment: Please put this, NSLog(@"-%@-",data); and tell me the output Please..

Comment: @ThilinaHewagama NSLog is Yes

Comment: why downvote i have written right code if it is not working then there is no need to downvote?

Comment: @JdeveloperIphone I checked ur code. It is going in if condition at my end.

Comment: @Jdeveloper Iphone, downvote most probably came because the code alone is not enough in this case, you should have showed more (educated) efforts to say if-else is not working.

Comment: Read Thilina's last comment again!!  Show us the EXACT (copy paste) output from the SECOND NSLog statement he posted (the one with the `-` characters).

Comment: What A-Live said -- saying "if" does not work is not at all helpful.  'if" is not broken -- you are doing something wrong.  Attention to detail is critical in programming.

Comment: where are the - characters in the NSLog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code,

```
 NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    data = [data stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);

    if ([data caseInsensitiveCompare:@"Yes"] == NSOrderedSame) {

        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:@"Successful Login" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
    else {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Incorrect user name or password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }
```

Comment: again same my NSLog is 2013-05-07 16:26:15.577 ProductivoApp[3183:c503]  Yes

Answer (score 0):

Use this as :

```
 if ([[data stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@"Yes"]) 
{

}
```

Edit : Your code is working fine as I checked it at my end.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: again same thing else is working

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check it now.

Comment: Hi I didnt understood your code, im bit like a beginner, can you please explain what id that